# Is there any indication when Android kills a service?

Tags: android, service, kill-process

I have a service running in its own process.  It appears fine in the evening, but after I've gone to sleep I think Android takes its axe to it.

Am I right in thinking that `onDestroy()` won't be called when Android kills a service?  If not, is there any other place the kill is registered?

I think I'm going to need to research the `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a service running in its own process.

Why is it in its own process?

> Am I right in thinking that onDestroy() won't be called when Android kills a service?

It may, it may not.

> If not, is there any other place the kill is registered?

No.

> I think I'm going to need to research the AlarmManager.

Users hate services that live forever, which is why task killers are popular. They hate services that run in their own process even more, because they consume extra RAM, CPU, and battery, typically for no good reason.

If your objective is to do something on a periodic basis, *please* use `AlarmManager` -- that's why it is there.

Comment: It's in its own process because I want it to have the option to start on boot and it has no UI except the configuration.

It doesn't live forever, just for the length of time specified in the config.

Anyway, having read Android's approach to its services, I can see that the using the AlarmManager to start my service at the appropriate time is a better approach than leaving it lurking around waiting.

Comment: @TomDestry: "It's in its own process because I want it to have the option to start on boot and it has no UI except the configuration" -- this does not require a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

Accordint to the [Service lifecycle](http://file:///F:/Android/docs/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) in the developer document, the `onDestroy()` method will be called when the service is killed or stops.

Also, if an app has a service running in the background(i.e a music player playing in the background), the system will consider that app is active and won't kill its process except extreme conditions( I don't think it happens in practice).

The document says:

```
Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this happens, the system will later try to restart the service. An important consequence of this is that if you implement onStartCommand() to schedule work to be done asynchronously or in another thread, then you may want to use START_FLAG_REDELIVERY to have the system re-deliver an Intent for you so that it does not get lost if your service is killed while processing it.
```

Here, what I am thinking about is that if a service is killed by the os, the os will try to restart it later. But, in this case, is the onDestroy() method called?I'm not sure. Have someone tested on this?

Comment: `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: Really? I know for the Activity, `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called. Is it the same for a service? The document states: "If the service is currently executing code in its onCreate(), onStartCommand(), or onDestroy() methods, then the hosting process will be a foreground process to ensure this code can execute without being killed. " However, I have never tested this.

Comment: Android can terminate a process at any point if it has an emergency need for RAM. When it does so, it does not bother calling `onDestroy()` on any of the running components in that process.